# Upload file in KVM guest

Tags: kvm, libvirt

Which library is best to use for uploading a file in KVM(Kernel Based Virtual Machine) guest?

Comment: Different ways to upload a file on kvm guest??

Answer (score 2):

May be [libguestfs](http://libguestfs.org) is what you're looking for, specialy the [virt-copy-in](http://libguestfs.org/virt-copy-in.1.html) and [virt-copy-out](http://libguestfs.org/virt-copy-out.1.html) tools ?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a linux guest, you could give 9p-virtio a try. It can share a directory between the guest and the host.
http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/9p_virtio

Answer (score 0):

This solution from David Weber works really well: http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/9p_virtio

Basically `mkdir /tmp/share && echo '/hostshare /tmp/share 9p trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L 0 2' >> /etc/fstab`. On Host ``mkdir /tmp/share`.

Then in Virt-manager, Add Hardware > Filesystem, change Driver to Path, add Source /tmp/share and Target /hostshare. And `mount -a`.

Or add by command `mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L hostshare /tmp/share`.